# Error on deployment of jhipster application on Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, deployment, jhipster, cloud-foundry

In advance, sorry about my poor english (i am working on it :-) ). 
It is also my first post on stackoverflow so i will be working on the good practice.

I builded a jhipster application  and worked on it locally in dev profile and it worked pretty well. So i tried to deploy it on Pivotal CloudFoundry with the "yo jhipster:cloudfoundry" sub generator and it packaged and uploading my app ( it seemed strange that the files uploaded was only of 6M).
But the app did'nt start. So i went to check the logs on the pivotal control panel and i saw that the app crashed after trying to start.

[Here is a link of the full stacktrace](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32701832/stacktrace)

I think that the problem comes from connection to the database and it's true that i don't remember seeing the binding of a database when i deployed the app.
Someone to help me please

Answer (score 0):

You're using prod profile but only application.yml seems to be loaded. So either you should configure your datasource in application.yml or you should upload also application-prod.yml if it's defined here.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer! I found a way to make it run. Seemed like it was the "MetricRegistry" which had a @Autowired annotation that makes the app crash. I still don't know why but after deleting the @Autowired, the app run.